# Can't group on this selection using Dates column from SQL in Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel, which I'd like to be able to performing `Grouping` on using the `SaleDate` column.

However, when I've created my Pivot Table, right click an element in the field and choose `Grouping...` I get the error that:

> Cannot Group on this selection

Which I've figured is because there is either

1) Blanks in the column, or

2) The column is not of date type Date *in Excel*

I've copied the whole column to Notepad++ and performed a `Find what: (a blankspace)` but that gave nothing in return, i.e. there are no blank spaces in the columns.

That leaves option number 2, and since I can't filter the `SaleDate` column on `Year` or `Month` it seems to in fact be interpreted as a `text` rather than a `Date`.

I'm using a SQL database as a source, which I have tried to adjust to parry this (my raw data to the SQL is of data type `numeric`, hence I first need to convert it to `varchar` and subsequently to `date` (note that these are Three different approaches I have used to adjust the date in SQL. I have noticed that the table to which I save the data is indeed of data type `date` in SQL):

```
left(convert(date,convert(varchar,Rawdate,110),110),7) as SaleDate
convert(date,convert(varchar,Rawdate,112),112) as SaleDate
convert(date,convert(varchar,Rawdate,110),110) as SaleDate
```

which returns, in order, `yyyy-mm`, `yyyy-mm-dd`, `yyyy-mm-dd` but none of these works to either Group on in the Pivot Table, **or** filter on `Months` or `year` in Excel.

Comment: Never worked with Excels connected to SQL, but may I suggest converting to `datetime` and seeing what happens? If the time part is a concern, you can clean it out in various ways, e.g. convert to `datetime` after your usual `date` conversion.

Comment: Can you post an image that shows what you see if you make the SaleDate a Row field and you click the filter icon? And can you also post here a couple of examples of the dates you're using? Even better, paste some of the dates into Excel, take a screenshot and post it here, and try making a PivotTable out of those dates and grouping the field. That will help diagnose the underlying issue.

Comment: @KtX2SkD       That did the trick! Converting to datetime, rather than date as I had previously tried, worked like a charm. I don't have the option to filter by `Month`, but I have by `year` and `quarter` and year is all I need really. Please consider making your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I never worked specifically on Excels that utilize SQL-Server directly, I know [SQL-Server has many date & time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql), unlike .NET's C# which has fewer, or Excel which has only one<sup>(1)</sup>. The types of SQL-Server itself are not that cooperative with each other to begin with<sup>(2)</sup>, so I wouldn't be surprised if issues arise from even the *tiniest* differences when trying to port to other technologies, which I faced a few times.

With that in mind, and your evidence of a likely failure in date conversion, plus the chained conversions you mentioned, my first suggestion is to **feed the Excel a different date type**, and my first choices would be **datetime** or **datetime2**, for being the most popular, the most complete, and the most similar to Excel's lonely type.

<sub>(1): It's more like zero, it's just an integer with everybody around it giving it special treatment, which they fail at half the time.</sub>

<sub>(2): Why would `int` to/from `datetime` be fine, but `int` to/from `datetime2` is not...</sub>

Comment: Thanks again and thanks for adding more information to the matter. I've seen many threads about the data types being wrong, but not in such a  good way as this, and particularly that `datetime` ought to resemble Excel's date type the most.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the field of interest a rowfield, and click on the "Filter" triangle in the column heading, then often right to the bottom of the list in that PivotFilter box you'll see the item(s) causing you the problem.  Be aware that it might be text that simply *looks* like a date, or it might be something more obvious as per the basic example in the screenshot below:

[image]

As per my comment, another way to diagnose what's going on is by taking just a few of the items that you are sure are dates, putting them into a range, making a PivotTable out of them, and seeing if you can group them. If you can, then you know that the problem is indeed likely some text in the data. If you can't, then it's likely you have text that still needs to be converted to dates...but you'll need to post some examples here in order for us to give you suggestions on how to turn it into something Excel recognizes as a date.